# Ionic Slider - how to select after specific slider by index after ng-repeat done?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this  element with **ng-repeat** to load data and create the slides (from a backend server).

I have a button where the user locks an specific slide, I save the status of "there is an slide locked" and the index of the locked slide.

So far so good, the problem is when user leaves that screen and come back later, if there is a "locked status" of some slider it must change to that slider using de index saved previously (I could not find a better approach for this).

So in the **$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function () {})** I have:

```
if ($rootScope.swiperLocked) {
  var nextSlide = 2; //$rootScope.initialSlide
  $rootScope.swiperLocked = false;
  $scope.slider.unlockSwipes();
  console.log('locked at ' + nextSlide);
  $scope.slider.slideTo(nextSlide); // This is NOT WORKING
  //$rootScope.swiperLocked = true;
  //$scope.slider.lockSwipes();
}
```

Template:

```
<ion-slides options="data.sliderOptions" slider="data.sliderDelegate">
  <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="card in profile.cards track by $index">
    <!-- content here -->
  </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```

What can I do to change for the specific index I have? Let's say I have locked the slide with index 2, then when I come back to this screen I want to show THAT slide.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function () {})` thing. Try with the *sliderOptions*.

Use `initialSlide` in the options:

```
$scope.data.sliderOptions = {
        'initialSlide': 0, // <-- Update your locked page index here!
        'loop': false,
        'direction': 'vertical'  // Or "horizontal"
        'speed': 300 //0.3s transition
};
```

Hope this help.